# How to avoid DoS in a proxy environment with 1 IP only

Tags: proxy, ddos

We have lots of servers behind a proxy (nginx) and an IP. Users are reaching to their servers through proxy. We add their domain to proxy and route traffic to their servers.

The problem is sometimes we get DoS or DDoS attack directly to IP not to domains. Besides using fancy DDoS Mitigator, is there a solution to avoid DDoS to the related IP ?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Mitigating DDoS attacks is Hard (and expensive).

There are companies you can pay money to, who'll either provide you with a box you put in your datacentre, which does packet-filtering, but is immune to being flooded off the network.  Such things are supplied by high-end firewall providers, like Arbor networks, etc..
I don't know how these things work.  Apparently they do, but as ever, YMMV.

There are also DDoS mitigation services as a service (if that makes sense).. You get a DDoS mitigation tool, provided on a Pay As You Go (although, it's actually more like a monthly fixed-rate contract).  You route all your traffic via their hosted service, and they provide you with a "clean pipe" which has been filtered by their cluster of expensive hardware.

The slow/old-fashioned way to do it is to work with your upstream provider to null-route the DDoS traffic before it reaches your servers.

I propose you do some googling around for DDOS mitigation services, I've given you one starting point in Arbor, who do both hosted and IaaS options, call a few vendors, go through the pre-sales spiel and let them fight amongst themselves for your custom.

There's a few reasonable starting points in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Handling).  Pretty much every high-end firewall vendor I can think of has their own flavour of solution for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments Tom. X as a Service seems to be a solution however I am not sure about the performance.

On the other I imagine that we buy those expensive stuff, but this leaves me with a question; what happens if the bandwidth is saturated and we have down time related to network saturation ?

Comment: Then you'll still have to either get a fatter pipe (which is why XaaS is a good option, because they have hyooooooge pipes).. or ask your upstream to filter it.

Comment: Our upstream told us that "they have DDoS protection" however it seems to be just a marketing activity :) We looked at Arbor devices, they told us that they have new mechanism that mitigates the activity on-premise and block the traffic from the upstream company in our case the telecomunication companies backbone. We will check that out for a test.

Comment: Interesting.. I'd love to know how that works, and whether it works for you.  Please come back with your findings, if possible.

Comment: Yeah definitely, it will be a pleasure :)

Comment: I met with Arbor representitives and they told me about the feature called "cloud signal". With this feature, if telecom company has arbor machine with cloud signal feature, the machine that we will buy will have the ability to get help from telecoms' machine. Here is the page; http://www.arbornetworks.com/arbor-partner/alliances/cloud-signaling-coalition